# How to programmatically reconnect to server when there is no working connection to the server?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Is there a function/method in socket.io to trigger a ping-pong event from the client-side?

I want to ensure that before the client emits an event that it has a working connection with the server.

For example, when the client goes into standby or sleep mode with the web application open in the background, the socket.io-client still thinks it's connected. I know this because the `socket.connected` is still set to `true`. It's true until the socket.io ping-pong or heartbeat event (I don't know what it is called internally) fails.

This is my "maybeReconnect" function that gets called before a `socket.emit()` call, but it doesn't work because of the reason above:

```js
const maybeReconnect: () => boolean = () => {
    /**
    * Manually connect to the socket server in case the socket is disconnected
    * this has to be done every time the client tries to emit a socket event
    * but isn't connected to the socket server due to many possible reasons
    * @public
    */
    if (socket && socket.disconnected && !socket.connected) {
        socket.connect();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

I don't want to disconnect every time, like in the code snippet below, because this forced reconnect would happen every time the client emits an event.

```
socket.disconnect();
socket.connect();
```

Comment: Unless the events happen many times a second, there's nothing wrong with disconnect/reconnect.  A socket does not know the other end is disconnected until it tries to communicate and fails.

Comment: @TimRoberts But what if? In my case the client does some HTTP get requests when it reconnects to the socket server to update its state, so I don't want to make unnecessary disconnect/connect calls. Only the ping-pong event of socket.io updates the socket.connected/disconnected state, all my socket events just go to the void when there is no connection but socket.connected is still set to true

Comment: It depends on the cost of the overhead.  If this is a "once a minute" thing, then who cares about some extra net traffic?  It's hard to make a robust socket app, because their is no async notification when a socket goes bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I buried myself into the socket.io docs and found out there are two built in events "connect" & "disconnect". With those two events I keep track of the current state of the connection.

Btw. Im using React with TypeScript.

```
socket.on("connect", () => setState(SocketState.Connected));
socket.on("disconnect", () => setState(SocketState.Disconnected));
```

On the server side the `pingInterval` gives the socket.io client the information how often it should pingpong with the server. So setting it to 1000 or 2000 will result in the client realizing in 1 or 2 seconds delay that there is no active connection to the server. Which in my case should be more than enough for the client app to update its UI & hold of any socket.emit() calls until its connected again.

```
import { Server as SocketServer } from "socket.io";


const io = new SocketServer<ServerToClientEvents, ClientToServerEvents, InterServerEvents, SocketData>(server, {
  pingTimeout:  2000,
  pingInterval: 2000,
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PATCH"],
    credentials: true,
  },
});
```

The reason I don't want to call `socket.disconnect()` with `socket.connect()` is that my app is fetching data on a custom reconnect I've coupled with `socket.connect()` and calling disconnect & connect every time before a emit would also work as Tim Roberts explained in the comments, but on my app one fetch is the same as 84077 bytes while one ping event is 62 bytes (54 TCP overhead + 8 socket.io). Which means I could pingpong every second for ~23 minutes until I have the size of one fetch.

FIY, there is also the built in "reconnect" event but it fires 3 on every reconnect.

```
socket.io.on("reconnect", (attempt) => {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing it for webApp what you can do is, fire **socket.connect()**
with [request-animation-frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), what that will do is, it will fire the event as soon as the user is active or starts using the webapp.